# Multiple API calls with same request

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I want to make multiple HTTP calls with the same endpoint passing different id. Is there a better way to handle this from UI. We cannot change the backend right now, **is there a better way?**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  loadedCharacter: {};
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    let character1 = this.http.get('https://swapi.co/api/people/1');
    let character2 = this.http.get('http://swapi.co/api/people/2');

    forkJoin([character, character2]).subscribe(results => {
      // results[0] is our character
      // results[1] is our character2
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: No. And posting a comment requires 15 characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are essentially 2 options:

1. Is the option you have where you use [`forkJoin()`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin) to combine all the observables into an array

   - **PROS:** you know you will have all your data loaded inside you `subscribe()`
   - **CONS:** you have to wait for *every* HTTP request to finish before `forkJoin` emits the value
   - *Note: you can implement a nice helper function like @Prince recommended*
2. You can use [`mergeMap()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/mergeMap) for your IDs and react whenever *one* of the observables completes

   - **PROS:** you don't have to wait for *every* HTTP request to complete. You can react *as they complete*. Also, you can handle errors easier (so if one request fails you can still continue with the other requests).
   - **CONS:** you have to handle your emitted values in the `.subscribe()` a little differently

At the end of the day, you will need to decided which approach is best for you. There isn't anything wrong with the implementation you have. I noticed you are keeping your `loadedCharacter` as an object, so honestly option 2 may be good for your use case

Example code for **Option 2**. See this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-5wm3bl) for a small demo:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, from, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  private endSubs$ = new Subject();
  loadedCharacter: {};
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    /* ids of all the characters you want to load*/
    const characterIds = [1, 2];

    /* this will emit each id as a value */
    from(characterIds).pipe(

      /* merge each id to an Observable of the http get request */
      mergeMap(id => this.http.get(`https://swapi.co/api/people/${id}`)),

      /* cancel any pending requests when the component unloads.
        this will avoid any RxJS memory leaks */
      takeUntil(this.endSubs$)
    ).subscribe(
      character => {
        /* note that you will only receive 1 character at a time */
        console.log('received character', character);
        this.loadedCharacter[character.id] = character; // or whatever you want to do
      },
      err => console.log('Error loading a character', err),
      () => console.log('All character requests have finished')
    );
  }

  /* clean up our subscriptions when the component destroys */
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.endSubs$.next();
    this.endSubs$.complete();
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** I added some RxJS cleanup code to avoid any memory leaks from the `mergeMap`. Any requests that are pending when this component unloads will be cancelled. [Here is an example SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41177163/8772013) explaining Observable cleanup, and [here is a relevant RxJS article](https://ncjamieson.com/avoiding-takeuntil-leaks/) on where to place your `takeUntil()`.

Comment: When you use [mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap) do not forget to unsubscribe and/or manage the numbers of concurrent inner observables to avoid memory leaks and you can use the second argument (resultSelector) to manipulate the data.

Comment: That is a good point. The OP didn't have any observable clean up so I didn't want to muddle up the code explanation, but I probably should just to remain thorough.

Comment: I hope I did not offend you, your response is great, it is more an advice/reminder for @Thalapathy to find the best solution without side effects.

Comment: No offense taken! I honestly just forgot. I get lazy sometimes when working with Observables that complete (like `http.get()` does). But it does make the answer better and will help others viewing it. Also there is still a chance the observable emits and completes _after_ the component destroys which could create some weird bugs. So thank you for the reminder!

Comment: use concatMap, so as not to increase server capacity

Comment: Yes, [`concatMap()`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/concatMap) is another option. `concatMap` would execute the requests in order. Meaning it would wait for the first request to complete, and then send the next. If overworking the server is a concern, you can definitely switch the `mergeMap` for a `concatMap`.

Answer (score 5):

You can extract the logic to create observable inside a common function and use it like below:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  loadedCharacter: {};
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    let character1 = this.createHttpObservable('1');
    let character2 = this.createHttpObservable('2');

    forkJoin([character, character2]).subscribe(results => {
      // results[0] is our character
      // results[1] is our character2
    });
  }

 createHttpObservable(id:string) {
   const url = 'https://swapi.co/api/people/';
   return this.http.get(`url${id}`);
 }
}
```